# Laravel: www redirection to non-www returns 404 on http

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, digital-ocean

I've hosted my Laravel app on DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache installed). I need to redirect the www domain to a non-www domain that has SSL enabled (HTTPS). However, when I try to go to `www.example.com` it returns a laravel 404 error page.

When I try to write the same `www.example.com` but starting with HTTPS (`https://www.example.com`) it redirects successfully to non-www. The only problem is when I try to go to `www.example.com` it shows an error.

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dukabox.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dukabox.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Is this only a problem when you implement the redirect in `.htaccess`? Can you request `http://www.example.com` successfully otherwise? If so, please include your complete `.htaccess` file as it sounds as if you have a conflict with other directives. "I need to redirect the www domain to a non-www domain that has SSL enabled" - the way that's written it sounds as if the SSL cert does not cover the www subdomain? But I assume that is not the case, since you seem to be requesting `https://www.example.com` without issue?

Comment: Hello @MrWhite no I can't redirect to http://www.example.com it results in 404. And yes, that is my complete .htaccess. I can't access the site if I only write www.example.com or http://www.example.com but url like https://www.example.com works perfectly